# How to get client computer name using php from remote server

Tags: php

I have already used following php script in remote server application but got null value ::

```
exec('wmic COMPUTERSYSTEM Get UserName', $user);
$pc_user = (explode('\\',$user[1]));
$download_location = "c:/users/$pc_user[1]/downloads/";
```

Result :: `Array()`

But in local pc I got the pc user name properly.

Comment: PHP works on your server, not on the client so you will not be able to get client-side information with PHP.

Comment: How can I get some document files from client side without file upload if my application on remote server?

Comment: How can I get some document files from client side without file upload if my application on remote server? I used bellow code for this purpose but it  is not working from remote server :                                                              copy($download_full_path, 'answer_files/org_doc_files/'.$down_file_name);

Comment: Short answer, you can't. The web server does not have access to the computer name that the connecting to the web server. It would be a HUGE security hole if you could get files from a client without them knowing.

Answer (score 1):

You can get following thorough PHP scripts

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // Returns the IP address of client
$_SERVER['RREMOTE_HOST']; // Returns the Host name of client
$_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT']; // Returns the port being used to communicate
```

Comment: This does not provide the computer name of the computer connecting to the web server. As the comment above says, you can not get the client machines computer name remotely.

Comment: Yes because it's not having access to client's file system through the browser.